# Parse XML in row/value format to custom objects in PHP

Tags: php, xml

Based on what I was reading it seems like the best way to parse XML in PHP is to use the `simplexml_load_string()` method. Every example that I found consisted of XML that have different child node names. In my case I have XML that is in a row/value format. I want to be able to parse each one of the rows into a custom object called 'Job'. So each row node in the XML represents a 'Job' and each data node represents a Job property. What is the best way to parse this type of XML in PHP?

Here is an example of the XML that I am trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset  xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!--
<dataset
    xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/ xmldata.xsd"
>
-->
    <metadata>
          <item name="RequisitionNumber" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
          <item name="Title" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
          <item name="City" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
          <item name="State" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
          <item name="PostalCode" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
          <item name="Description" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
          <item name="Requirements" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
          <item name="ID" type="xs:string" length="52"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value>16-1279</value>
            <value>Manager</value>
            <value>Portland</value>
            <value>OR</value>
            <value>98660</value>
            <value>Manager Description goes here</value>
            <value>Requirements go here</value>
            <value>45</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>16-1279</value>
            <value>Exec</value>
            <value>Portland</value>
            <value>OR</value>
            <value>98660</value>
            <value>Exec Description goes here</value>
            <value>Exec go here</value>
            <value>45</value>
        </row>
    </data>
</dataset>
```

This the path I have started down:

```
class Job
{
        function __construct($requisitionnumber, $title, $city, $state, $postalcode, $description, $requirements)
        {
            $this->RequisitionNumber = $requisitionnumber;
            $this->Title = $title;
            $this->City = $city;
            $this->State = $state;
            $this->PostalCode = $postalcode;
            $this->Description = $description;
            $this->Requirements = $requirements;
        }    
}

function ParseReportResult($xml)
{
    $jobs = array();
    foreach($xml->row) 
    {
        //How do I parse each data node into the below object?
        $job = new Job($requisitionnumber, $title, $city, $state, $postalcode, $description, $requirements);
        array_push($jobs, $job);
    }

    return $jobs;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you a variable named `$dataset` that contains your xml example, you access it as shown below:

```
function ParseReportResult($xml)
{
    $jobs = array();
    foreach($xml->row as $row) 
    {
        $requisitionnumber = (string) $row->value[0];
        $title = (string) $row->value[1];
        $city = (string) $row->value[2];
        $state = (string) $row->value[3];
        $postalcode = (string) $row->value[4];
        $description = (string) $row->value[5];
        $requirements = (string) $row->value[6];

        $job = new Job($requisitionnumber, $title, $city, $state, $postalcode, $description, $requirements);
        array_push($jobs, $job);
    }

    return $jobs;    
}
```

You call your function like this:

```
$doc = simplexml_load_string($dataset);
$jobs = ParseReportResult($doc->data);
```

You should make sure the values are in the correct order for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should access using the path "data/row" and then using the indexes from "value". It only works if each data tag have the same values at the same positions:

```
$content = new SimpleXMLElement($xmldata);

foreach($content->data->row as $item){
   print_r($item->value);   
   $requisitionnumber = $item->value[0]->__toString();
   $title = $item->value[1]->__toString();
   //...
    $job = new Job($requisitionnumber, $title, $city, $state, $postalcode, $description, $requirements);

}
```

The metadata tag contains information about the "value" columns, so you could ensure reading the right positions reading from

```
$content->metadata->item[$position]
```